# JavaScript String object is being split into an array on jQuery.post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to do ajax calls - many of which are working fine, but I've just run into an odd problem trying to send a string to the server. I've narrowed the code down to just this:

```
var x = new String('updateGroup');
var y = 'updateGroup';
$.post('page.aspx', {
    f: x,
    f2: y
}, function(data) {
});
```

When it hits the server however, the request variables are as follows:

```
Request["f"]          null          string
Request["f2"]         "updateGroup" string
Request.Form.AllKeys  {string[12]}  string[]
  [0]                 "f[0]"        string
  [1]                 "f[1]"        string
  [2]                 "f[2]"        string
  [3]                 "f[3]"        string
  [4]                 "f[4]"        string
  [5]                 "f[5]"        string
  [6]                 "f[6]"        string
  [7]                 "f[7]"        string
  [8]                 "f[8]"        string
  [9]                 "f[9]"        string
  [10]                "f[10]"       string
  [11]                "f2"          string
```

where `Request["f[0]"]` contains `"u"` etc.

Can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you throw away all details, what's being executed in your case is:

- `jQuery.post`
- which calls `jQuery.ajax` internally to do the ajax
- which calls `jQuery.param` internally to build the query string

The point is that `new String` is not a primitive string but a string *object*, and will **pass** the [following check](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L636) in `jQuery.ajax` (`typeof new String("foo") === "object"`, not `"string"`):

```
// Convert data if not already a string
if ( s.data && s.processData && typeof s.data !== "string" ) {
    s.data = jQuery.param( s.data, s.traditional );
}
```

`jQuery.param` is executing [as follows](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L791):

```
for ( var prefix in a ) {
    buildParams( prefix, a[ prefix ], traditional, add );
}
```

This means it does a `for in` loop over the string, which indeed puts each character separately in the query string.

You can check this behaviour with this testcase:

```
var x = new String("abc");

for(var i in x) {
    console.log(i, x[i]);
}

// 0  "a"
// 1  "b"
// 2  "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use **new String** you create a string object rather than a string itself, if you run this in your browser you will see they're an object and a string respectfully:

```
console.log(typeof new String("hello"));
console.log(typeof "hello");
```

More information here (including why you can an array of characters posted to the server):
http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/string.html

Comment: Thanks - makes sense.  I added a .toString and .valueOf and both seem to work around the issue.  Seems odd to me that Jquery would treat string objects this way - seems counterintuitive to me.

Comment: The String object is a bit of an archaic relic, it has methods like big, bold, blink, fontsize, fontcolor etc. gives you a good idea of it's age ;-)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript [distinguishes between a literal string and an object of type String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects).
I suspect that when the jQuery post method is inspecting the data object you have sent it, it checks if the `typeof` each value is `string`. If it is, its job is done. If it finds an Object (which a String is) it iterates over it - which is why you're getting an array of characters.

if you have a String object you can use `String.valueOf()` to get the primitive value

Answer (score 1):

You should never create a string like this in javascript, it's considered a bad practice:

```
 var x = new String('updateGroup');
```

but always like this

```
 var x = 'updateGroup';
```

because in the first case you create an object and only in the second case you create a string. The same goes for arrays, always use

```
 var array = [];
```

Comment: A wise man once said: do not make instances of trivial variables :-) +1

Comment: The string object itself is coming from a layer of code away from this example - though now I'm revisiting that layer to investigate where it came from I'm wondering if it actually needs to be a string object at all - it's being constructed from the .val() of an input box, but I don't see any reason for it to be this way so will look at changing that layer instead of everyone who uses it having to worry about using valueOf.